# Laravel modify relationship accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model called `Message` which has a column `created_by` where it refers to the id of the `User`. Im using Eloquent to retrieve the model and I want to change the `created_by` field to the full_name of the User instead of returning the id.

I've tried to modify the accessor like this:

```
public function getCreatedByAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->full_name;
}
```

But then I get a error: `Exception in Response.php line 60:: Failed calling App\Entities\Message::jsonSerialize()`.

Comment: Post the full error message, to include the file and line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Please post the controller action (or route closure) where you handle the response?

Comment: Use different name for the accessor OR the column.

Comment: Where is `$this->user` set? Are you expecting this from a relationship? Otherwise, you'll need to create that object.

Comment: Yes this is the relationship. If I rename my accessor it does work, but it would be better if I could just replace an existing columnname..

Comment: @guidsen You can't just replace column name, since your relationship depends on it. And with an accessor the relationship can't work, because accessor depends on.. relationship. It will be neverending story, you just can't do it this way.